# unable to set FormGroup value for p-autocomplete while trying to edit datatable row

Tags: angular, primeng, form-control

I have `datatable` edit. When I click on edit button a popup displays with all `formcontrol` values populated except for `p-autocomplete`.

Below is the code.

HTML:(below html code is for `p-autocomplete`(PrimeNG))

```
[suggestions]="cities" [forceSelection]="true" formControlName="city" field="value" (completeMethod)="selectedcity($event)" [minLength]="3"
```

Script:

```
onRowEdit(c: UserAddr) {

    this.valid = false;
    this.userAddrForm.setValue({
      mgAddrId: c.mgAddrId,
      lineA: c.lineA,
      lineB: c.mdPostalCd.area,
      lineC: c.mdPostalCd.suburb,
      city: c.mdPostalCd.city,
      province: c.province,
      zipcode: c.mdPostalCd.zipCd
    });
    this.index = this.addresses.indexOf(c);
    this.displayDialog = true;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: are you sure the value of c.mdPostalCd.city is defined ?

Comment: yes it is. getting the value